# The Select2 Plugin and 508 Compliance

Tags: jquery-select2

**Question**

The Select2 control introduces 508 issues, as displayed by the Axe plugin for Chrome. How to make Select2 508-compliant?

My understanding is that there is a project called [SelectWoo](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2017/08/08/selectwoo-an-accessible-replacement-for-select2/) which makes **Select2** (the dropdown control) **508-compliant (accessibility)**.

But how do [SelectWoo](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2017/08/08/selectwoo-an-accessible-replacement-for-select2/)'s versions map to Select2's? If I'm using Select2 4.0.3, and then need to upgrade, does SelectWoo have its own versions? Is it a separate branch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have resolved Select2's 508 compliance issues (without switching to any other alternatives).

All that's necessary is these 4 lines, after the initialization `$(field).select2({..})` :

```
$(".select2-selection").removeAttr("role");
$(".select2-search__field").removeAttr("role");
$(".select2-search__field").attr("aria-label", "textbox");
$(".select2-search__field").attr("type", "text");
```

This got rid of the 508 errors displayed by Axe on all Select2 field(s) on a given page. If there are multiple Select2's, these 4 lines can be added at the very end of your `document.ready`, they'll take care of all the control instances at once.

Comment: Thanks!  This cleared the violations I was seeing using the WAVE plugin too.

Comment: I think this answer is an example of "accessibility by formula" and it would be better to investigate the reasons for these attributes existing, and the practical effects they have on screen readers and other assistive technologies. For example, these attributes are probably set like a text box because Select2 does indeed allow free-form text entry for searching.

Comment: "Accessibility by formula" being a term I just made up to describe the practice of measuring and designing for accessibility only by some automated tools, rather than real-world testing.

Comment: Doesn't this just make the accessibility worse? I assume the roles were there for a reason.

Comment: If it passes Axe, we assume it's accessible! If it doesn't, it's not!